# ADF Copy Data remove index in oracle Sink

Tags: oracle, azure-data-factory

I am trying to insert data from a SQL table to an Oracle table using activity Copy Data in Data Factory, on the first try it runs fine but on the second try it throws an error that an index on the target table (Oracle) has been corrupted.

[image]

Searching in different forums I found that apparently the Copy Data activity sends the insert statement in the following way: INSERT /*+ SYS_DL_CURSOR */ INTO

any idea how to fix this???

Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

As per the error index is not corrupted. It was used twice. May be the operation was not planned according to the schedule and worked parallelly.

The Copy activity is executed on an integration runtime. You can use different types of integration runtimes for different data copy scenarios:

1. When you're copying data between two data stores that are publicly accessible through the internet from any IP, you can use the Azure integration runtime for the copy activity. This integration runtime is secure, reliable, scalable, and globally available.
2. When you're copying data to and from data stores that are located on-premises or in a network with access control (for example, an Azure virtual network), you need to set up a self-hosted integration runtime.

Use either of the two operations mentioned above, the error will be resolved.

Check link for support document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview

Comment: Hi !!!SairamTadepalli-MT:  The execution of the process is carried out through a self-hosted IR, this must be done in this way due to security guidelines, tests were carried out and, effectively, when using the activity of copying data, the indexes are damaged, which is a clear sign that the data copy activity corrupts or disables indexes in this case an oracle table